# Не работает скрипт клик по кнопке

Tags: javascript, jquery

при нажатии на кнопку "Собрать" и потом в модальном окне "Купить" не срабатывает такой скрипт

```
$('#new_window .info ').on("click", ".make_comp", function() {
       //add_to_cart();
       //return false;
       alert("sdfsdf");
    });
```

Comment: Так а клик по `#new_window .info` или по `.make_comp` ?

Comment: .make_comp , вот на сайте http://technogik.ru/kalkulyator-sborki

Comment: @EugenEray, видимо `.make_comp` динамический

Comment: да , после формирования конструктора и по нажатию на собрать в модальное выводится html с этой кнопокой

Comment: блока `.info` у вас так же при навешивании слушателя нет, так что видимо надо так: `$('#new_window ').on("click", ".info .make_comp", function() {})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чего-то у Вас еще нет на странице в момент назначения обработчика.

```
$(document).on("click", "#new_window .info .make_comp", function() {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#new_window').click(function() {
   //add_to_cart();
   //return false;
   alert("sdfsdf");
});
```

Проще сделать так

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
  $('#new_window .info ').on("click", ".make_comp", function() {
       //add_to_cart();
       //return false;
       alert("sdfsdf");
    });  
});
```